# Adding vertical scrolling for IKImageBrowserView that is created programmatically

Tags: cocoa, macos, ikimagebrowserview, vertical-scrolling

I would like to create a Cocoa library Test.dylib that provides Icon view using IKImageBrowserView. I cannot create IKImageBrowserView in nib since dylib does not support Resources. So, I am creating the IKImageBrowserView programmatically as follows:

```
IKImageBrowserView *browser = [[IKImageBrowserView alloc]initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
Datasource *ds = [[dataSource alloc]init];
[browser setDataSource:ds];
[browser setDelegate:ds];
```

But, when there are more items than visible area vertical scrollers should be displayed which is not happening.

How do I support scrolling for IKImageBrowserView that is created programmatically?

I have tried the following with no positive results:

```
NSScrollView *scroller = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
[scroller addSubview:browser];
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with trying to place the IKImageBrowserView inside of a NSScrollView.  However, instead of using addSubview (inherited from NSView), use setDocumentView…

```
NSScrollView *scroller = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
[scroller setDocumentView:browser];
[scroller setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
```

The [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003461-SW1) has some good info in it…

> NSScrollView instances provide
>   scrolling services to its document
>   view. This is the only view that an
>   application must provide a scroll
>   view. The document view is responsible
>   for creating and managing the content
>   scrolled by a scroll view.